# Is there a way to calculate missing values by combining other known values?

Tags: r, dplyr, time, missing-data

I have a dataset with longitudinal data in long format. For each id, I have the number of years since their baseline assessment. For some of the assessments, I have the year it occurred but not all assessments have this information. I am trying to fill in missing years based on the time elapsed between assessments.

```
   id    years_since_baseline      study_year 
1  1                  3.09              NA
2  1                  3.87              NA
3  1                  4.91              2021
4  1                  6.36              NA
5  2                  0                 2018
6  2                  1.02              NA
7  2                  2.40              NA
8  3                  13.9              NA
9  3                  15.0              NA
10 3                 15.71              2017
```

Ideally I could calculate the missing study year by using the years_since_baseline (e.g. for row 6, study_year = 2018 + 1.02 = 2019.02) producing something that looks like:

```
   id    years_since_baseline      study_year 
1  1                  3.09              2019.08
2  1                  3.87              2019.96
3  1                  4.91              2021
4  1                  6.36              2022.45
5  2                  0                 2018
6  2                  1.02              2019.02
7  2                  2.40              2020.40
8  3                  13.9              2015.19
9  3                  15.0              2016.29
10 3                 15.71              2017
```

However, the assessment with year information varies between ids - some have it as the first assessment, others in the middle and some at the last assessment. Also, I will have to calculate the time elapsed between each assessment.

I have tried using combinations of group_by, fill and lag to calculate the missing years but with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `mutate()` along with `group_by()` to calculate an estimate of the baseline year for all rows in each group (I include `mean()` just in case there is more than one row per id with the study year present).

Then use this column with the `years_since_baseline` to calculate the missing `study_year` values.

```
have <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3),
                   years_since_baseline = c(3.09,  3.87, 4.91, 6.36, 0, 1.02, 2.4, 13.9, 15, 15.71),
                   study_year = c(NA,  NA, 2021, NA, 2018, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2017))

want <- have %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    mutate(
     # calculate estimated baseline year
        est_baseyear = mean(ifelse(!is.na(study_year), study_year - years_since_baseline, NA), na.rm=TRUE),
     # use this to calculate a new study year for rows where it is missing
        study_year = ifelse(is.na(study_year), est_baseyear + years_since_baseline, study_year)
           ) %>% 
     # drop the estimate column
    select(-est_baseyear)
```

I think this gives your required output. However, I would have a concern about the fact that the original `study_year` variable is a whole number so these calculations might be biasing the results toward an earlier year. Maybe use `round(est_baseyear + years_since_baseline)` in the calculation of `study_year` to mitigate somewhat against this.